# Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3

Tags: java, oracle, maven

[image]I am a beginner to Maven project. In my project, I am getting the error `Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3`, even though the jar was present in my repository at the correct folder. Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: please share your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the binary license, there is no public repository with the Oracle Driver JAR, so you cannot just add it to your pom file.

You have to add this jar manually:

First, you have to download `ojdbc6.jar` from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3)
click  `jar (2.6 MB)` on the middle of the page.

Then put `ojdbc6.jar` in some folder in your project (let's use `lib`).

Then you have to add this in your `dependencies` section in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Another option is to install this jar in your local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

And then you will be able to reference this dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You have to choose what's best for you.

Comment: Alternatively if you run a local nexus installtion in your company you could use 'mvn deploy' to deploy the artifact to it so everybody in your team can use the artifact. I don't know whether the oracle license allows that, though.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ojdbc6 folder from the .m2 repository completely and then maven update the project in enclipse  that solved my problem

Comment: where is .m2 repository, i dont have maven installed locally. i have it on eclipse

Comment: Here you go  @JunaidShirwani `C:/Users/<yourMachineUsername>/.m2` folder

Comment: This answer is now outdated as above https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238897/2940265

Answer (score 2):

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Should solve the issue if you are using spring boot

Comment: This won't resolve the issue because now Oracle removed their dependencies from public repos to oracle one. You have to follow their guidelines unless you manually

Answer (score 1):

Once you face the issue . Check in your maven user settings path . This will be a path something like :

> C:\Users\ *user name*\ .m2\repository

Open the location and go to **oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.3** folder and put the .jar on that location .Return back to eclipse perform maven update and your issue will be gone.