# Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0.7.0

Tags: java, oracle, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0.7.0

[image]

I am using Spring tool suite IDE for developing spring maven project which is similar ecllipse IDE, I found Solutions for this issue on stackoverflow but it doesn't work for me'.
I tried two links:

- [Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238622/missing-artifact-com-oracleojdbc6jar11-2-0-3)
- [Oracle JDBC ojdbc6 Jar as a Maven Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898499/oracle-jdbc-ojdbc6-jar-as-a-maven-dependency)

but still I am getting

> Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0.7.0

error in pom.xml, I am now stuck at this point.

Comment: Best solution is to start using a repository manager and install into that repository manager. The simple reason is that Oracle has never deployed jdbc drivers to Maven central..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because of ojdbc jar is not available on maven repo. so you have to add this dependency from local relative path

```
      <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.1.0.7</version> 
<scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
       </dependency>
```

You can download ojdbc jar from [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html](http://Oracle%20site)

Comment: This will not work cause you missed `<scope>system</scope>` apart of never a good idea of having system scoped dependencies. Better using a repository manager...

Comment: Furthermore this will produce a [WARNING starting with Maven 3.5.2](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.2/release-notes.html) see [MNG-6207](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6207).

Comment: @khmarbaise , Ajit Kamble thanks it works for me, but i have another project I haven't used <scope> and <systemPath> tags and their its working fine,I can't understand why, can you have any idea?